# O(n^2) solution to maximum product subarray results in 'time limit exceeded' dilemma in leetcode

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, memoization

I was attempting to solve the maximum product subarray leetcode problem (https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-product-subarray/) **in python** but **only 186/188** test cases passed, the remaining two producing the **time limit exceeded** error, inspite of the solution being O(n^2).

What am I doing wrong ?

```
class Solution:
def max_element(self,a,b):
        if(a>b):
                return(a)
        else:
                return(b)
def compute_product(self,products,i,j,array):
        if(i==j):
            products[i][j]=array[i]
            return(array[i])
        if(products[i][j]!=-1):
            return(products[i][j])
        products[i][j]=self.compute_product(products,i,j-1,array)*array[j]
        self.compute_product(products,i+1,j,array)
        return(products[i][j])
def max_product_subarray(self,table,products,i,j,array):
        if(i==j):
            table[i][j]=array[i]
            return(array[i])
        if(table[i][j]!=(-1)):
            return(table[i][j])
        result=-99999
        case1=0
        if(products[i][j]!=-1):
            case1=products[i][j]
        else:
            case1=self.compute_product(products,i,j,array)
        case2=self.max_product_subarray(table,products,i,j-1,array)
        case3=self.max_product_subarray(table,products,i+1,j,array)
        result=self.max_element(case1,self.max_element(case2,case3))
        table[i][j]=result
        return(result)
def compute_max_product_subarray(self,array):
    table=[[(-1) for j in range(len(array))]for i in range(len(array))]
    products=[[(-1) for j in range(len(array))]for i in range(len(array))]
    return(self.max_product_subarray(table,products,0,len(array)-1,array))
def maxProduct(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
    return(self.compute_max_product_subarray(nums))
```

Comment: "inspite of the solution being O(n^2)" > what makes you think that's a good time complexity? The problem can be solved in O(n).

Comment: @Nelfeal okok, so I need to implement the O(n) sol for all test cases to pass ?

Comment: Don't ask me, I'm not the author of the problem. But it seems likely.

Comment: @DebalGhosh - or at least O(log n)...

Answer (score 0):

If the values are a mix of positives and negatives and/or zeros, the answer includes only the largest candidate windows with an even count of negatives and no zeros, and the zero candidate. Count the number of negatives between each zero or end of list. For each count, if the count is even, the candidate is the product of all the elements in that section. If the count is odd, check two candidates; one from the earliest positive before the second negative element to the end of the section, and the other from the beginning of the section to the last positive passed the second to last negative element. The 0 candidate might be relevant in case no positive candidates can be formed.

Comment: Your logic has problems.  For `[-2, -2]` it would say that the answer is `-2` but in fact it is `4`.

Comment: @btilly oh, good point. Is it better now?

Comment: You missed the trivial case of `[-1]`.

Comment: @btilly no, that one is covered by the word, "might," in the last sentence :)

Comment: There is no 0 and therefore no 0 candidate.  Unless you allow empty lists (for a 1 candidate), none of them cover it.

Comment: @btilly hence the word, "might." If the zero candidate is not there, the sentence still validates "no positive candidates can be formed."

Comment: Yes, you don't say to produce 0 when neither zero or positive candidates exist.  But you don't say WHAT to produce.  Given that there is only a single possible answer, it is trivial to figure out the right answer.  However your solution doesn't say what it is in that case.

Comment: @btilly agreed. My solution does not state what the answer is in the scenario where there is only one possible answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of maximum-sum-subarray can be solved in O(n) time complexity. With maximum product-subarray, the algorithm can be made faster by partitioning the array around the zero values and scanning within these partitions. Any crossover across these partitions are always zero, so that does not need any computation.